# Read SQL-File from C# (MVC) VisualStudio 2017

Tags: sql, oracle, file, streamreader

hello I create an intranet page with MVC, also I want to connect an ORA-SQL database.

my idea was to create a folder (Query) [in my Project] in which my SQL files are stored:
- DevStats.sql
inside the query.

Now I want to start a query:

> OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand ();
>
> command.CommandText = query;

What is the most efficient way to read the file (StreamReader?)? And where can I find the file then (relative path)?

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Query\DevStats.sql", Encoding.Default))
{
   return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

is null

> @"\Query\DevStats.sql"
>   is also null

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpServerUtility.MapPath()` to get physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path.

Simple Code could be like

```
HttpServerUtility.MapPath("/Query/DevStats.sql");
```

[HttpServerUtility.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)